# Bulding a context menu addin for Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook

This is going to be a bit of a noobie question, and though there exist pages that try to enlighten me on the given topic, none of them are noobie-friendly enough.

So I turn to you guys.

I've been tasked with building a simple addin for Outlook 2010, where the user can right-click an email, which then opens a new window of options. Thus far, I don't care much about the content of the window, just that a customer can right-click on an email to open it.

The tools I have at hand are MS Visual Studio, Outlook 2010 and my skill in C#.

Please note, that I'm not asking you guys to do the task **for** me, just maybe help me get started?

I'd love some example code on how a context menu can be added to Outlook, if someone could give a quick demonstration?

Deeply appreciated you guy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest starting from the [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) article in MSDN.

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is used for customizing context menus in Outlook. The [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) and [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) articles in MSDN describe all the required steps for custiomizing context menus in Outlook/Office. Pay special attention to the [Context Menu for a Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforaMailItem) section. When Outlook displays the following context menu, a mail item is selected in the current view:

```
<contextMenus>    
  <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
    <button id="MyContextMenuMailItem"
        label="ContextMenuMailItem"
        onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
   </contextMenu>  
</contextMenus>
```

When Outlook displays the following context menu, multiple items are selected in the current view.

```
<contextMenus>    
  <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMultipleItems">
    <button id="MyContextMenuMultipleItems"
        label="ContextMenuMultipleItems"
        onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
  </contextMenu>  
</contextMenus>
```

You can read more about the Ribbon UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Very useful! And a far more detailed answer than my own! Thank you Eugene!

Answer (score 0):

Going to go ahead and answer my own question, as some Googling and some goofball experimentation got me a presentable button.

Finally, I got a lot of the solution from Microsoft here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554969.aspx

Surely worth a read if you want to create some basic context menus, and you're as green as me.

Answer (score -1):

Hi if you are making a commercial product I strongly recommend buying https://www.add-in-express.com/ it's going to make your life much, much easier. The dll wraps office object and the same line of code will work with office 2003- 2013.

Take a look here

https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/02/07/office-shared-addin-task-panes-outlook-regions/

Comment: It doesn't matter what component/framework is used to create an add-in. Moreover, it is not related to customizing context menus. I'd suggest leaving such feedback as comments.